# Running Windows 8.1 app built on Windows 10 with VS 2015

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Built on Windows 10 with VS 2015, our (managed) Windows 8.1 Store app crashes on startup with an odd XAML parsing error on devices running Windows 8.1 (no stack trace or source file given, just caught in the unhandled exception handler, so no chance to debug):

> Cannot deserialize XBF metadata property list as 'HorizontalContentAlignment' was not found in type 'null'.

Additional info:

- Built on Windows 8.1 with VS 2015, the app will work properly
- The app will run correctly on Windows 10 devices
- The app is sideloaded on the Windows 8.1 devices

As of the [Visual Studio 2015 compatibility guide](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx), the scenario should be supported. Did someone already experience the same issue and overcame it?

Comment: Related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f964f85-a933-4273-aa01-c0ad1279774f/w81cannot-deserialize-xbf-metadata-property-list-as-padding-on-windows-81-but-not-windows-10?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: I see the exact same error. Only my setup is different. I build our App under Vs13 on W10. Locally deployed the App runs. When remotely deployed to a Win 8.1 machine then I see exact same error on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I usually trace such cryptic errors to a style or template resource files, and as you indicate I don't find Visual Studio to be as helpful as it should. If you inspect style or template files (e.g., generic.xaml, or your own custom style files, etc), and if some things are missing, Visual Studio usually flags this with a blue wavy underline (I must say not always accurate but about 90% in my guesstimate).

This may turn out to be a non-answer but sharing my experience of XAML parsing errors that leave no clue to go on.